# Show $\phi : S_3 \rightarrow S_3$ given by $\phi(f^{i}g^{j}) = f^{2i}g^{j}$ is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

> Show $\phi : S_3 \rightarrow S_3$ given by $\phi(f^{i}g^{j}) = f^{2i}g^{j}$ is an automorphism

I'm not really sure how to begin.

I know that I need to show that $\phi$ is a group isomorphism, but the problem is more confusing for me when written in terms of $f$ and $g$.

For example, how do I show injective and surjective?

Comment: My process would be long but you can do this in this way if it's really an automorphism, First interpret S_3 as the cyclic permutation notation by elements 1,2,3 and plug each of this into f,g now Note check there orders because it must repeat and you can deduce i, j to lesser values with almost length of C ycle should be 6. S_3 has order 6 and order of an element divides order of the group. So it is just factors of 2.3 so i, j can take values 1,2,3,4,5,6 rest is just checking properties of isomorphism and Done.

Comment: What do $f$ and $g$ represent here?

Comment: The elements of cycles created by 123 in S_3 for example one element is (1 3 2)

Comment: $S_3=\{f,g,e,f^2,g^2,f^{2} g |f=(1 2 3), g=(1 2)\}$

Comment: If here $f, g$ can be any member of $S_3$, then I do not think $\phi$ is well-defined. For instance, use $1$ to denote the unit element of $S_3$, then $\phi(1)=\phi(1\cdot 1)=1$, but let $f, g\neq 1$ and $fg=1$, then$\phi(1)=\phi(fg)=ffg=f\neq1$, hence $f$ not well-defined.

Comment: Please look at the answer in the post.

Comment: @above Op is new in MSE and might not know How to express his ideas although, people with mind can understand what he/she trying to say for the god sake because when mentioned he don't known how to write S_3 in terms of f,g.

Comment: I am not taking Op's side but Op should be more careful. @Op next time plz try to explain ur thoughts clearly.Framing of the question is way bad

Answer (score 0):

I am reframing the question a bit because the question is not well Defined,(And Op Should be more careful about Making and Suggesting questions)furthermore there will be ambiguity of understanding what $f,g$ actually is?. The question should be framed actually like this,
Show that there exist,  $f,g\in S_{3}$ such that there may exist automorphism $$\phi : S_3\longrightarrow S_3$$ satisfying $$\phi(f^{i}g^{j})=f^{2i}g^{j}$$

$\textbf{Proof:}$ We know that $S_3$ using generators can be represented as,

$$S_{3}=\{f,g,e,f^2,fg,f^{2}g|f^3=e , g^2=e , gf=f^{2}g\}$$ Now, we have
$$\phi(f^{i}g^{j})=f^{2i}g^{j}$$
Note that this is similar to, $$\phi(f^{i\pmod 3}g^{j\pmod 2)})=f^{2(i\pmod 3)}g^{(j\pmod 2)}$$ Thus enough to consider $(i,j)\in\{0,1,2\}\times\{0,1\}=\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)\}$
Trivial to check
$$f^{0}g^{0}\longrightarrow e$$, $$f^{1}g^{0}\longrightarrow f^2$$,$$f^{2}g^{0}\longrightarrow f^4=f^{3}f=e.f=f$$, $$f^{0}g^{1}\longrightarrow g$$,
$$f^{1}g^{1}\longrightarrow f^{2}g$$, $$f^{2}g^{1}\longrightarrow 
f^{4}g=fg$$

Hence, $\phi$ is a automorphism. $\blacksquare$

Remark/Try: Find all integers $(m,n)$ such that $$\phi_{m,n}(f^{i}g^{j})=f^{mi}g^{nj}$$ is an automorphism from $S_3$ to $S_3$ for some particular element $f,g\in S_3$ that may exist in $S_3$. Note each $(m,n)$ pair gives different functions.